# Why is my DataGridView not updating changes on the underlying DataTable

Tags: c#, .net

This is my code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        using (SqlCeDataAdapter sqlCeDataAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM test", sqlCeConnection))
        {
            sqlCeDataAdapter.Fill(table);
        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).Rows.Count.ToString());
    }
```

What I'm trying to do is to update the underlying database, but according to [this](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-binding-a-datagridview-to-a-database) tutorial, the underlying `DataTable` would need to reflect the changes made on the `DataGridView` whenever I edit the rows. What I'm doing is just running the app, pressing `button1`, then deleting some rows in the `DataGridView` and then pressing `button2` to see how many rows I get. On this app I get the same amount of rows as before deleting rows, but if I replace `dataGridView1`'s `DataSource` with a `DataTable` that I populate myself (By calling `DataTable.NewRow()` and so on), the changes are reflected on the `DataTable` every time I delete a row (the underlying `DataTable` contains less rows after I delete some of them).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems to be incomplete even if you compare it with the article that you are referring to.

In the article itself, it is the BindingSource which is used to achieve the functionality that you are trying to achieve. Refer the code below as used in that article.

```
//BindingSource to sync DataTable and DataGridView
BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
```

Since you seem to be learning about this, i wont give you exact code but pointers in the general direction.

See how the above object is being used in the example tutorial. That should help you simulate behaviour similar to what you are looking for.

Also, one more hint, once you make some changes after binding a grid to a data source, you do have to TELL the data source to *update* itself. This too is covered in the tutorial's sample code.

Hope this helps! I also suggest that you read the MSDN both related to [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx) and [DataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) as you need to use both in conjunction for your functionality to work as you would like it to.